# By viewing the polynomials as a difference of two squares, factorise the following polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, factoring, completing-the-square

By viewing the polynomials as a difference of two squares, factorise the following polynomial:
$$x^4+x^2+1.$$
I searched but couldn't find a way to solve this

**Edit**: By using Hans Lundmark hint, I get:

$$(x^2+1)^2-x^2$$

Is it fully factorized?

Comment: Now use $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a hint: $(x^4+2x^2+1)- x^2$.

Comment: Is the final answer: $(x^2+1)^2-x^2$

Comment: @Mr.Mohamed Factorized means written as a product, this isn't. You got a difference of squares, why not go all the way?

Comment: @ Mohamed: note that $x^4+x^2+1=x^4+x^2+x^2-x^2=x^2+2x^2+1-x^2$ so you have the result in @Hans answer.

Answer (score 0):

We don't factorization:

$$\dfrac2{x^4+ax^2+1}=\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^4+ax^2+1}-\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^4+ax^2+1}=\dfrac{1+\dfrac1{x^2}}{x^2+a+\dfrac1{x^2}}+\dfrac{1-\dfrac1{x^2}}{x^2+a+\dfrac1{x^2}}$$

Now as $\displaystyle\int\left(1\pm\dfrac1{x^2}\right)dx=x\mp\dfrac1x,$

for the first integral, choose $x-\dfrac1x=u$ and $x+\dfrac1x=v$ for the second

Use $x^2+\dfrac1{x^2}=\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)^2-2=\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)^2+2$

Comment: I assume you wanted to answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336886/factorize-x4x21), where it involves the integral

Comment: @farruhota, No, that will be closed as duplicate,right?

Comment: Well, how does it help the OP here? Your answer is not a polynomial factorization and integration is not asked by OP... I see you and the user aryan bansal on the link posted similar answers almost at the same time. So, nevermind!

Comment: @farruhota, Sorry didn't see that :)